# Mysql Calculate two strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like that :

Name : Example

```
ID | PRICE | MATH

1  | 10.00 | * 1.3

2  | 20.00 | +2

3  | 30.00 | 35%
```

Is there a way to calculate / update the column PRICE.

For example; the ID 1 is something like that :

```
10 * 1.3
```

So:

> UPDATE Example PRICE ???  MATH ? WHERE ID='1'

Thanks for your time,

Comment: This sounds explosive to me

Comment: This sounds like no research effort has been done.

Comment: You'll have to use dynamic SQL.  In other words, dynamically generate the update statement and then `execute(strSQL)`  If Math was in two seperate fields you may be able to case the operation and do all the math w/o dynamic SQL.

Comment: Perhaps with a stored procedure, or you could do it in PHP.  Best to split the `math` column in to an `operation` column and a `value`.  That would be a lot safer, and you could use a `CASE` statement to do the work.

Comment: if you wanna do all of this i would suggest you place the opperation symbole at the end. All you would need is to calculate the string length then substr the parts. Leaving you todo a function to calculate the patterns. But this would be a very non efficient way too so i'm for the idea that you should use Dynamic SQL.  My +1 @xQbert

Comment: +1 for @xQbert suggestion. But if you are using dynamic SQL, your data should be fix so it will consistent, which mean that the first character in `Math` column should be an operator `+, /, *, -`, i see that your ID=3 is not begin with an operator.

Answer (score 3):

The `MATH` is column in the database that contains free expression which you have no control over? This seems like awful design.

Not knowing anything about your app and why you'd want to do such insane thing, I'd suggest to make it at least more obvious and easy to parse:

```
ID | PRICE | COEFFICIENT | ACTION

1  | 10.00 | 1.3         | MULTIPLICATION

2  | 20.00 | 2           | ADDITION

3  | 30.00 | 0.35        | MULTIPLICATION
```

Then you can do some `IF/ELSE` in the database or directly in the server-side language but still, describe what is your use case...

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The real answer here is that you shouldn't do this and should do it on the application side.

Comment: Its pretty easy to understand. IF I have 2000 price.

Answer (score 0):

Bad table design. But if you must use it, you can use prepared statement to execute a dynamic query.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html